# how use confirm before deleting in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#Delete').on('click', function() {

    var no = $('#bill').val();

    if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this record ?'))
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/Bill_Delete"+no,
        type: 'DELETE',

        error: function() {
          alert('Something is wrong');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //  $("#"+no).remove();
          alert("Record removed successfully");  
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is view page code...

```
public function Bill_Delete(){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    //$Search = $this->input->post('Search1');

    $this->User_model->Bill_Delete($_POST["no"]);
}
```

this controller code...........

```
public function Bill_Delete($no)
{
    $this->db->where('billno', $no);
    $this->db->delete('salesitem');
    $this->db->where('no', $no);
    $this->db->delete('salesbill');
    echo "Successfully delete";
}
```

this is model code

my prblm is how to create confirm message.in this simply shows the message and it not delete into database..............

Comment: You shouldn't mix PHP and JS - it's a bad practice that can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Please try changing url to ` url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/Bill_Delete/"+no,
        type: 'POST'` and then test

Comment: shows an error Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: no

Filename: controllers/TipUp_Loan.php

Line Number: 49

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\application\controllers\TipUp_Loan.php
Line: 49
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding this window.confirm in your button tag

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')">Delete<i class="icon-bin position-left"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified:

The problem is that you are not sending the value of variable 'no' in your AJAX call. Use 'data' property of Jquery AJAX to send the variables. Also, use type: 'post' for the AJAX call. 
Here is the modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#Delete').on('click', function() {

var no = $('#bill').val();

if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this record ?'))
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/Bill_Delete",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { no: no },
    error: function() {
      alert('Something is wrong');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Record removed successfully");  
    }
  });
}
});
});
```

And inside you controller:

```
    public function Bill_Delete(){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    //$Search = $this->input->post('Search1');

    $this->User_model->Bill_Delete($_REQUEST["no"]);
    }
```

The rest is fine with your Model and Controller. Thought the way you are mixing JS and PHP looks so ugly as suggested by ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs.

Comment: Look at the modified code. Remove the concatenated part in URL in your AJAX call. And in your controller, use $_REQUEST['no'] instead of $_POST['no'].

Comment: it is working but shows error message like undefined index

Comment: s sir it is deleted in database but it shows an error undefined  index no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182853/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-osama-ibrahim).

Comment: Mark this as accepted answer if it solved the problem for you :)

Answer (score 0):

i have another answer

```
<button type="submit" id="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You sure want to Delete')" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete<i class="icon-bin position-left"></i></button>
```

by using this can confirm box has been enabled